Spontaneous Polarization on a n-doped system ( ABO3 perovskite ) in VASP
I am trying to perform a spontaneous polarization calculation on a n-doped ABO3 system using the berry phase approach in VASP. I use a 3x3x3 supercell and I am trying to follow the same way we calculate polarization for pristine unit cell, by creating the intermediate symmetries and finding the polarization branch. I am not getting a proper polarization though. I am new to this type of calculation with defects and don't know how to proceed. Also in situations, where we cannot obtain polarization branch, does it mean the calculations are wrong ?
